# Multiple RingCentral Sandbox Accounts

Tags: ringcentral

Having walked through multiple tutorials now, I've accrued *multiple* "sandbox accounts" within my dev account. Is this a problem? Is there a way to merge or otherwise reuse these sandbox accounts for testing? Is there a problem with adding multiple, disparate permissions to a *single* account and reusing it for more than one project?

Comment: Using multiple tutorials should not result in multiple "sandbox accounts", but multiple "applications", each with a ClientId and ClientSecret. Multiple sandbox accounts would involve different logins (username/passwords). Do you actually have multiple applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per I know, linking account for RingCentral can be done only in production.
As per the following link ***"RingCentral Account Linking provides a set of features to support customers that are split across different accounts"*** :
https://support.ringcentral.com/s/article/9415?language=en_US

Not sure if you can do it to your development or sandbox account.
You can followup with RingCentral back-end developer support team and request them to merge at ***devsupport[at]ringcentral.com*** or you can contact support [here](https://success.ringcentral.com/RCContactSupp?src=).

Although you can add multiple users in same developer sandbox account you want